# Custom Post Type Pagination Not Working or Single Posts Displaying?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, page-template

I want to create a page to display all the 9 recent posts within that custom post type. (this is where I'm getting confused) I've called the page template `page-podium.php` ( my custom post type is podium, see below )

My `page-podium.php` kind of works. It displays them but I'm having trouble getting the pagination to work, is it in the correct place? it seems to multiply the links over and over.

And lastly. when i click on the custom post type post to go to the actual page it says "Page not found", this is the bit im confused the most about, is it loading them via `page.php` or `single.php`? or do i need a `page-podium-page.php` or something?

Here's my code...

**Post Type Podium:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'podium',
        array( 
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Podiums' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Podium' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        )
    );
}
```

**Page Template**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: The Podium
 *
 * The 'Gallery' Page for the podium posts.
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

          <article class="podium col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <h1>The Podium</h1> 

            <ul>
               <?php query_posts( 'post_type=podium&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
              <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnails' ); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <?php endwhile; else : ?>

            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>


            <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
           <?php endif; ?>


          </article><!-- Article End -->                  

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please don't use external links to add your code. You can add your code directly into the question which will be easier for viewers. For formatting help you can review How to [Format Posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I've went ahead and modified your question to add your code so that you get the idea of what it looks like.

Comment: if you want to add pagination on your custom post template then [CPTPagination](https://gist.github.com/amitrh/d1c070cc85b956354f37) i think help you